# Swift SKSpriteNode: Complex Sprite Textures?

Tags: swift, skspritenode

This is a question regarding best-practice for implementation.  For an example, I will reference a simple game called [Pixel Claw](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.playicg.pixelclaw).

Suppose I had an `SKSpriteNode` akin to the claw from Pixel Claw, in that what the `SKSpriteNode` might be ''holding'' is variable (but finite in possibilities, e.g. four different objects).

What the node `SKSpriteNode` is holding has no agency of itself.

Thus my question is: is it better to use different textures such as a claw, a claw holding object a, a claw holding object b, etc or have two `SKSpriteNode`s and position the `SKSpriteNode` with the claw texture to be next to the `SKSpriteNode` with an object texture?

I am not making a claw game, it was just the first example that popped to my head where both could be plausible solutions. The former being more simplistic - just switch the texture, the latter being more generalizable.

If the latter is the best solution all around, how can one ''pair'' the movements of the two sprites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the second approach especially if the objects a and b can fall out of the claw at some point.

You should make the texture of a claw, the texture of object a, and the texture of object b.

To make the objects move in sync with the claw, simply add the object as a *child* of the claw node. This way, moving the claw will cause the object to move as well!

Note that before adding the object as a child, you need to make sure that the object does not have a parent. If it does, you must remove it from its parent before adding it as a child of the claw. The same thing applies when you "release" the object from the claw: you need to first remove the object from its parent (the claw) and then add it as a child of the desired parent.

Comment: That is a very insightful answer, I didn't realize parent / child relationship for `SKSpriteNode`'s worked like that.  Could you maybe provide some pseudo code?

Comment: @SumNeuron The hardest part is just drawing textures really. You just call `object.removeFromParent()` first to ensure that it doesn't have a parent. Then call `claw.addChild(object)` to add the object as a child. You would also need to set the position and anchor points of `object` to make sure it is in the right place. You don't even need an if statement.